# Best place/time to create a dynamic model in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing a simple software as a service like app where each customer defines a set of configuration for a specific component. Then at runtime I need to construct a range of models based on this configuration.

My question is when should I lookup the configuration and build the array of dynamic ember objects to represent these models?

Currently I'm playing around with this inside the setupControllers function of the ApplicationRoute itself (as it's only loaded 1x when the app is loaded and then I'll have the array of models at any moment instead of waiting for them just in time later on.)

This set of configuration is minimal and the performance gains from this approach are worth it for this example. But is this the right component to load these up / create dynamic models?

Comment: A good place to do this could be in DS.Store.modelFor. You can check if the model exists, and if not create a new one. The only problem is: DS.Store.modelFor can not do anything async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is when should I lookup the configuration and build the array of dynamic ember objects to represent these models?

It depends of course ;-)

- If you need ember to be in a `loading` state while the lookup happens, then `setupControllers` is too late. In that case consider using the `model` hook instead.
- Do you need to do all of this configuration upfront? If not maybe push it down to `setupControllers` callback on a subroute.

> But is this the right component to load these up / create dynamic models?

Yes - in this case I'd say `setupControllers` on application route is a good choice.

Comment: This configuration should be loaded just 1x at app startup (because the configuration is setup in another SPA altogether). I'll use the setupControllers hook in the ApplicationRoute for now as it seems like the best place for something like this.